# Spring @RequestBody Mapping maps all attributes to null values from clean camelCase POST Postman request

Tags: java, spring, rest, request

I have a backend made with Spring.
In one of my controllers, i have a POST Request which receive data from a DTO which is implemented.
I use @Data annotation with Lombok, and the problem doesn't come from here... Because i try whithout it  too and it's doesn't work also.
When i send a POST request from Postman with clean Json formated with camelCase, my controller receive "null" data from my DTO... I don't understand why.
Can you give advices or help please ?
Thanks

**MY DTO**

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class TransactionSendPaymentToSomeOneDto {

  private String connectionEmail;
  private String connectionFirstname;
  private String connectionLastname;
  private String connectionIban;
  private String descriptionTransaction;
  private Double amountSendMoneyValue;

}
```

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/transactions")
public class TransactionController {

  @Autowired
  private TransactionService transactionService;

  @PostMapping("/{idUserSessionEnv}/payment")
  public ResponseEntity<Transaction> sendPaymentToSomeone(@PathVariable("idUserSessionEnv") Long idUserSessionEnv, @RequestBody TransactionSendPaymentToSomeOneDto selectedSendMoneyValue){
    try{
      log.info("RECEIVING DATA FROM FRONT-END: ID USER = "+idUserSessionEnv +" IBAN = " + selectedSendMoneyValue.getConnectionIban() + "  AMOUNT TRANSACTION = "+ selectedSendMoneyValue.getAmountSendMoneyValue());
      return ResponseEntity.ok(transactionService.sendPaymentToSomeone(idUserSessionEnv, selectedSendMoneyValue));
    }catch (NoSuchElementException nse){
      return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
  }
```

[image: POST request from postman]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending wrong payload.

The correct payload will look like this:

```
{
    "connectionEmail":"axel@axel.com",
    "connectionFirstname":"Axel",
    "connectionLastname":"Vega",
    "connectionIban":"2222",
    "amountSendMoneyValue":999,
    "descriptionTransaction":"Essai de transaction"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add **@ResponseBody** bellow the @PostMapping("/{idUserSessionEnv}/payment") ?

Comment: With @ResponseBody it doesn't work too

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).